# Overlay geom_col end to end in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I currently have a plot with only two columns.
I want to alter the position of these columns in a way that they are laid against each other horizontally.

Currently, I am working with this plot :
[image]

What I want is the bars to stack against each other horizontally such that their colors remain intact and the graph becomes more wide.
How can this be done?

Here's how closely can I describe how I want the plot to be :
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean exactly? Perhaps a sketch of what you're looking for would be helpful?

Comment: @AllanCameron hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
test <- data.frame(team = c("RCB", "SRH", "SRH"), results = c("win", "win", "win"))

test %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = results)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = team)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]